# Mysql - 1:n relationship

Tags: php, mysql

```
A table : id, name
B table : id, a_id, name
```

1A : nB

i want to select a record in A and related information in B with result like below

```
array( 
    0 => aID_1, 
    aName_1, 
    array (
       bName_1, 
       bName2 , .v.v.v
    ),
  ... 
  ...
)
```

Can i do it with only on query ?

Comment: you have cardinality 1:N, is it necessary create 2 tables?, can't you absorb it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA as a LEFT JOIN tableB as b ON a.id = b.a_id;
```

Comment: So i need to manipulate the result to get the structure that i want

Comment: @Chameron, Well, in that case it seems to above has already been answered more detail :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$qry = mysql_query ("SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name as b_name FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.id = B.a_id");
$data = array ();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_rows($qry))
{
    if (!array_key_exists($r["id"], $data)
    {
        $data[$r["id"]] = array (
            "id" => $r["id"],
            "name" => $r["name"],
            "b" => array ()
        );
    }

    $data[$r["id"]]["b"][] = $r["b_name"];
}
```

and now you can iterate via foreach:

```
foreach ($data as $d)
{
    print_r($d);
}
```

Comment: Can we do it only with mysql ?

Comment: You get all Results with one SQL Statement, because you join 2 tables. To get the results right in an PHP Array, you need PHP for it.